# Consistent ordering for product of variables

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find a bivariate function $f(x,y)$ satisfying the following differential equation $$\partial_y\big(yf(xy,y)\big)=0.$$ However, if I use the Mathematica function DSolve as follows: `DSolve[D[y * f[x * y,y],y]==0,f,{x,y}]`, I get the "The arguments should be ordered consistently" error. Is there any way to make this work?

Note that I am quite new to solving differential equations with Mathematica and, hence, this might be a stupid mistake that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: You can not have function $f(xy,x)$. It  needs to be $f(x,y)$ or $f(y,x)$. And please post plain text Mathematica code used. This is the code I used `ClearAll[f, x, y];
ode = D[y*f[x*y, y], y] == 0;
DSolve[ode, f[x, y], {x, y}]` to obtain the error message you showed.  `DSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.`

Comment: I assumed that this was the case. Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: Try: `DSolve[{D[f[x, y] == 0, y]}, f, {x, y}] `  This gives the solution:  `{{f -> Function[{x, y}, C[1][x]]}}`where C[1] is an arbitrary constant

Comment: @DanielHuber But that is a completely different equation.

Comment: Sorry I messed up.

Comment: You can define $g(x,y) = f(xy,y)$, use (if you like) Mathematica to solve the equation for $g$, which is $\partial_y (y g(x,y)) = 0$, then get $f$ using $f(u,y) = g(u/y,y)$.

Comment: I could indeed see that with a change of variables I can untangle the independent variables. But I do not fully understand why Mathematica is not able to do this itself?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

[image: pde]

Making the substitution z = x*y your differential equation becomes

[image: pde2]

Solving that, DSolve returns

```
Function[{z, y}, 1/z C[1][y/z]]
```